# Second-order tensor contractions and matrix multiplication

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, matrix-elements

The fluid dynamics book I'm reading lists the possible contractions of $A_{ij}B_{kl}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are second order tensors. Since I'm dealing with fluid dynamics, assume $ 1 \leq i,j,k,l \leq 3.$

Here's one contraction
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i} A_{ij}B_{ik} &= A_{ij}B_{ik} = A^T_{ji}B_{ik} = \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B}\\
\end{align*}
$$

However, since I can change the order of the scalars $A_{ij}B_{ik}$ , I think I could also write
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i} A_{ij}B_{ik} &= A_{ij}B_{ik} = B^T_{ki}A_{ij} = \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A}\\
\end{align*}
$$
which seems to suggest that $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A}$, which isn't true generally.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

---

Edit, my book actually did not write $A^T_{ij}B_{ik} = \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B}$. Instead, the author wrote

> Note also how the terms have been rearranged until the summed index is adjacent; at this point they can be written as a product of matrices.

which is partly why I was confused.

Comment: Your equations do not make sense: On the LHS, you have two free indices, on the RHS none...

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something but I think both sides of both equations have free indices $j,k$.

Comment: How does $A^TB$ have free indices?

Comment: This is what you did wrong: $\mathbf{B}^T$ in tensor notation is $B_{\color{red}{ki}}\,.$ Therefore $\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A}$ in index notation is $B_{\color{red}{ki}}A_{ij}$ which is different from $A_{ij}B_{ik}$ even if you change the order of the scalars.

Comment: $A^T_{ji}$ is ambiguous, since $(A^T)_{ji} = A_{ij}$ Also, $A_{ij}$ is not a scalar, since it is not invariant under a rotation. If the tensor is defined over the reals, then it's just a number that depends on coordinates. ${\bf A}$ does not depend on coordinates, and it's not a matrix either. It's a geometric object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two contractions are kind of correct,
except that the indices were missing in the final term:
$$A^T_{ji}B_{ik} = (\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B})_{jk}$$
and
$$B^T_{ki}A_{ij} = (\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A})_{kj}$$

As you can see, they are not quite same because
the order of indices is different.
Actually it shows that
$$\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B} = (\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A})^T$$

Comment: Just to be clear: With the usual understanding of notation, the equations in the question are *not* correct. The indices are important and actually, as you've pointed out, the source of confusion.

Comment: @TobiasFünke You are right. I have improved my wording.